# Why does WebdriverIO browser object prematurely exit my loops?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, webdriver-io

Whenever I use a method on **WebDriverIO's browser object**, it completely **breaks out of whatever loop I'm in.**

The debugger confirms this. It doesn't execute any other code in the rest of this loop. The loop should **iterate 51 times** which it does. **But it never executes the rest of the code after browser.methods()**

[image]

Here is the code:

```
  await redirects.map(async (obj) => {
    
        iterator7 += 1;
    
        console.log('In map method...');
    
        giveMeURLString = await browser.url(obj.Origin); //Why does this return / reloop????
        //  Also why is giveMeURLString populated with undefined
    
        iterator8 += 1;
    
        console.log('I should be able to see this...')
    })
```

You can also run the test yourself here:

https://github.com/DavidMLink/WebDriverIOBug

Why is it prematurely exiting my loops?

Comment: [Please see why we shouldn't post images of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with Async/Await. Using a simple ""synchronous loop"". Any type of for loop like "for of" or "for in" or "for" will do the trick.